# Problem when trying to reposition images in the BoxLayout in the Kvlang

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm creating an app with Kivy and I want it to have a header with an Image at the left corner and some buttons like a menu on this Image's right side. The problem is that I can't reposition the Image. I'm able to resize it but its position is always on the starting position of the BoxLayout.

I've tried changing its position with pos_hint and pos. Also tried resizing the Image with size_hint or setting size_hint to (None, None) and them tried to change its position again and none of them works. I've also added some buttons on the ScrollView below it that when pressed show the Image's position to check if something works.
Here is the Kvfile, I'm just pasting the Screen(SomeScreen) widget where this problem is ocurring

```
<SomeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            id: box
            size_hint: 1, 0.12
            canvas:
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            Image:
                id: img
                size_hint: None, 0.9
                width: 200
                pos: 200, 600
                allow_stretch: True
                source: 'image.png'


        ScrollView:
            id: scr
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                Button:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    width: 400
                    height: 200
                    on_press: print(f'image size: {img.size}, image postion {img.pos}')
                Button:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    width: 400
                    height: 200
                    on_press: print(box.size, box.pos)
                Button:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    width: 400
                    height: 200
                    on_press: print(scr.size, scr.pos)
```

I'd like to change the image's position to whatever I choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to note:

- You are using a `BoxLayout` with `orientation` set to `vertical`.
  That will position your widgets vertically, so the `ScrollView`
  will not be to the right of your `Image`.
- You have a second `BoxLayout` inside your first `BoxLayout` that
  appears to serve no purpose. However, putting your `Image` in a
  `horizontal`(the default) `BoxLayout`, means that you cannot adjust
  the `horizontal` position of the `Image`

Not sure if I have captured what you intention is, but here is a modified version of your `kv` that, I think, is more along the lines of what you asked for:

```
<SomeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            id: img
            size_hint: None, 0.12
            width: 200
            pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: 'image.png'

        ScrollView:
            id: scr
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                Button:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    width: 400
                    height: 200
                    on_press: print(f'image size: {img.size}, image postion {img.pos}')
                Button:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    width: 400
                    height: 200
                    on_press: print(box.size, box.pos)
                Button:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    width: 400
                    height: 200
                    on_press: print(scr.size, scr.pos)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The scrollview is intentionally below the image, I'll just add buttons to the Image's side when I reposition it. However you have found the solution. I didn't know that when the boxlayout is set up horizontally you cannot reposition its widgets horizontally, so I set it up vertically and now I can reposition the Image horizontally. Thank you very much!